# Prototyping with Adobe XD offline

Tags: prototyping, adobe-xd

I'm using adobe XD for UX projects on windows, but due to security I can't share it through adobe cloud network. Is there a way to use it confidentionally offline somehow for prototyping designs with customers?

I also googled it and was amazed, because as I got it ([from here](https://adobexd.uservoice.com/forums/353007-adobe-xd-feature-requests/suggestions/12942726-sharing-prototype-in-a-closed-network)), it isn't new (it's from March 2016 - 2 years!) and many people have the same security policy in their companies (for a reason), but perhaps there's some workarounds.

I doubt there is an alternative for adobe XD on windows, but if you have anything, please share you thoughts.

Comment: Sketch is a good alternative.

Comment: But sketch isn't available on windows

Comment: Oops missed that. Avocode isn't bad, and Figma has promise. 

Sad reality is Adobe is slow and rolling out features so you might just be out of luck.

Comment: So, email your client the files?  If they don't have XD to view them, what about simple screen captures?

Comment: Or use an online editor like [gravit](https://designer.gravit.io/) - I have no affiliation with this site.

Comment: If you and or your clients work in a corporate environment you should be able to use to a non-corporate security level (normal) wireless network just when you want to share the online link? (Which I assume is what you're trying to do. BTW I was in corporate network for years with regular CC and it's total hell. There's the CC enterprise team solution but I've never tried it. You might want to look into Axure as I believe you can export your prototype as HTML files from that.

Answer (score 1):

You can share it protected with a password
[image]

Comment: OP states "I can't share it through adobe cloud network" so that doesn't answer it.

Answer (score 0):

I think adobe XD is something you can keep holding on to, it's really promising. Since you can't use the cloud share, try capturing each artboard(export the entire art board with ctrl+e) or you could record a prototype while you're using it on the system by clicking on a grey dot on the top left hand side of the menu bar.

[image]

For recording options, use (windows key+G)